# How to specify parameters with spaces when starting a new process

Tags: c#, .net, parameter-passing

i would like to run a process with the parameter: filename.

```
    string parms =  filechooser.Filename ;      
    psi = new ProcessStartInfo("timidity", parms);
```

The problem occur when user choose a filename with some spaces.
Ho can i pass the parameter with the "  "  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
string parms =  filechooser.Filename ;      
psi = new ProcessStartInfo("timidity", "\"" + parms + "\"");
```

Answer (score 5):

You could wrap the value in double quotes:

```
string parameters = string.Format("\"{0}\"", filechooser.Filename);
psi = new ProcessStartInfo("timidity", parameters);
```

Answer (score 3):

That should work just fine, the spaces will be passed too.

However if you want to escape the filename (which depends on the app being started, i.e. timidity), do this:

```
string parms = string.Format("\"{0}\"", filechooser.Filename);
psi = new ProcessStartInfo("timidity", parms);
```

This will create a string based on the format `\"{0}\"`.  `\"` becomes a quote (`"`) and `{0}` will be replaced with the first parameter after the format string, i.e. the filename.

You can try this out using the Start, Run feature or command prompt (`cmd.exe`).  Enter timidity then your full filename, with spaces, in quotes and see if that works:

```
timidity "my filename"
```

Answer (score 1):

Backslash is your friend:

```
"\"timidity\""
```

Comment: Nope, it's the filename that has the space, not the program to be launched ("timidity" doesn't have a space in it)